# como fazer um pattern background com CSS?

Tags: html, css, html5

Estava olhando os templates do bootstrap e [esse template](https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-new-age/) me chamou atenção pois o seu background é feito com a técnica [pattern](https://g.co/kgs/krKhfH), ou seja ele possui apenas uma imagem que se repete "perfeitamente" por todo background. Como posso fazer um bg assim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara isso é com `background-size` se precisar e `background-repeat`.

No exemplo aqui é apenas uma imagem que se repete na horizontal e vertical ocupando toda a página, mas na realidade a imagem tem 100px X 100px com size de 50px, o tamanho do BG é opcional e vc usa se quiser controlar o tamanho do *pattern*.

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background-image: url(https://www.lokoloko.es/16144-small_default/geometric-pattern-pack-234-pieces.jpg), linear-gradient(red, blue);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: 50px; 
}
```

Essa é a imagem original que usaram no site que vc citou como referência, e por traz eu fiz um `linear-gradiente` para dar a cor do fundo

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background-image: url(https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-new-age/img/bg-pattern.png), linear-gradient(to left, purple, tomato);
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

**OBS:** Link da imagem do site que vc citou como exemplo: https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-new-age/img/bg-pattern.png

Comment: isso mesmo! muito obrigada amigo!

Comment: @hunterxhunter Sem problemas tmj! O legal da técnica é que vc consegue com uma imagem pequena e leve cobrir a tela inteira!

Comment: Com certeza! Só mais uma coisa, tem como colocar 3 cores nesse gradiente?

Comment: @hunterxhunter tem sim meu caro, basta colocar uma cor a mais na lista `linear-gradient(to left, red, blue, green)` depois da uma olhada nesse link https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp